# wxpython to display text ,images,audio ,video on the same ctrl

Tags: python, wxpython

I wender if there is standard or custom control on wxpython to display text and other media to gather ,i mean something similar to web browser.
i tried webview but it is not support html5 elements of media.

Comment: Always post your code.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "No". wxPython does not have such a control. I do think webview will get you the closest to what you want. For video, you will have to use wx.Media:

- http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.media.MediaCtrl-class.html

If you really need to have an all-in-one control, then you'll have to create your own custom widget or look at a different UI toolkit to see if they have the widget you need.